# Payload requests - string concatenate layout error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have code that reads a list of numbers that are parameters for a python order:

```
def search(number):
    url = "http://localhost:8080/sistem/checkNumberStatus"
    payload = '{\n\"SessionName\":\"POC\",\n\"celFull\":\"'+number+'\"\n}'
    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

object = open('numbers_wpp.txt', 'r')
for numbers in object:
    search(number)
```

But, when I print the payload of my json the output is:

```
{
"SessionName":"POC",
"celFull":"5512997708936
"
}
{
"SessionName":"POC",
"celFull":"5512997709337
"
}
{
"SessionName":"POC",
"celFull":"5512992161195"
}
```

When reading the file with 3 numbers, the quotes in the `celFull` attribute closed correctly only in the last loop (last number), while the first two were broken into quotes. This break is giving error in queries.

Comment: I'm assuming `'numbers_wpp.txt'` is a file that has each number on a different line. The `for numbers in object` is iterating over the file line by line. Each line ends with a `\n` (newline character) except for your last line / last number. `search(number.strip())` will remove the whitespace on the line and only send the number as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `numbers_wpp.txt` is a file that has each number on a different line, the following code would iterate over the file line by line.

```
for number in object:
    search(number) # <--- numbers is actually a line in your file.
```

Since each number is on a new line, the preceding line has a `'\n'` at the end.
So

```
123
456
```

Is actually

```
123\n456
```

So number is actually `123\n`. This causes your payload to have a `\n` before the quote closes.

You could fix this by calling `number.strip()` which strips whitespace from either end of the string.

Alternatively, you should consider not using a handcrafted json string and let the requests library do that for you. [Documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request)

```
def search(number):
        url = "http://localhost:8080/sistem/checkNumberStatus"
        payload = {"SessionName": "POC", "celFull": number} # <-- python dict
        response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
   
object = open('numbers_wpp.txt', 'r')
for line in object:
    number = int(line.strip()) # <-- convert to an integer
    search(number)
```